# Arduino + SIM808 HTTP GET POST headers

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to get working SIM808 with Arduino. Can GET and POST GPRS HTTP request but only what cames on it's just body from server side `{"error":true,"message":"Unauthorized"}`
but I need header as it brings cookie for session.

```
+CREG: 0,1

AT+SAPBR=3,1,"Contype","GPRS"

OK

AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","giffgaff.com"

OK

AT+SAPBR=3,1,"USER","giffgaff"

OK

AT+SAPBR=3,1,"PWD",""

OK

AT+SAPBR=1,1

AT+SAPBR=2,1

+SAPBR: 1,1,"xx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

OK
AT+HTTPINIT

OK
AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1

OK
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","http://www.xxx.co.uk/index.php"

OK
AT+HTTPPARA="UA","MH Tracker"

OK
AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","Content-Length: 42"

OK
AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

OK
AT+HTTPSSL=0

OK
AT+HTTPDATA=41,30000

pass=xxxx&user=xxxx&action=xxxx

OK

AT+HTTPACTION=1

OK

+HTTPACTION: 1,401,39

AT+HTTPREAD

+HTTPREAD: 39

{"error":true,"message":"Unauthorized"}

OK

AT+HTTPTERM
```

I got some results, but with error, looks like my code have some junk characters

any advice

```
POST /client/index.php HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: www.mhprojects.co.uk
Content-Length: 41

pass=xxx6&user=xxx&action=xxx

SEND OK
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Thu, 01 Feb 2018 00:38:56 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 357
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1



400 Bad Request

Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.


Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Arduino code

```
    char data[350]="POST /client/index.php HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nHost: www.mhprojects.co.uk\r\nContent-Length: 41\r\n\r\npass=xxx&user=xxx&action=xxx";
int PowerOn = 12;//Power on pin
int Reset = 11;//Reset pin
char aux_str[50];
//////////////
void setup() {

  pinMode(PowerOn, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Reset, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);// UART baud rate

  power_on();

  Serial.println(F("Powering ON"));
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(F("Connecting to the network..."));

  while( send_command("AT+CREG?", "+CREG: 0,1", 1000)== 0 );

}

/////////////
void loop() {

char buffer[200];

if (send_command("AT+CIPMUX=0", "OK", 2000) == 1)// Selects Single-connection mode
  {
  if (send_command("AT+CSTT=\"giffgaff.com\",\"giffgaff\",\"\"", "OK", 2000) == 1)// Sets the APN, user name and password
    {
      if (send_command("AT+CIICR", "OK", 10000) == 1)// Brings Up Wireless Connection
        {
          if (send_command("AT+CIFSR", ".", 3000) == 1)// Gets Local IP Address
            { 
              if (send_command("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"www.mhprojects.co.uk\",\"80\"","CONNECT OK", 10000) == 1)// Opens a TCP socket
                  {              
                     sprintf(aux_str,"AT+CIPSEND=%d", strlen(data));
                     if (send_command(aux_str, ">", 1000) == 1) {

                     send_command(data, "SEND OK", 1000);

                     while (true)  {

                     read_UART_buffer(buffer,sizeof(buffer), 0);

                     }
                     Serial.println(buffer);
                     }
                                }   
                                else
                               {
                             Serial.println(F("Error setup TCP connection\r\n\r\n"));   
                           } 
                        }
                      else
                    {
                  Serial.println(F("Error getting the IP address\r\n\r\n"));      
                }
              }
             else
           {
         Serial.println(F("Error bring up wireless connection\r\n\r\n"));
        }
      }
    else
  {
Serial.print(F("Error setting the APN\r\n\r\n"));
    }
      }
        else
        {
          Serial.print(F("Error setting the single connection\r\n\r\n"));
         }

    send_command("AT+CIPCLOSE", "CLOSE OK", 1000);

    send_command("AT+CIPSHUT", "SHUT OK", 1000);

}

////////////////
void power_on() {

        // power on pulse
        digitalWrite(PowerOn,LOW);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(PowerOn,HIGH);
        delay(3000);
        digitalWrite(PowerOn,LOW);
        delay(3000);
}

///////////////
void reset()  {
  digitalWrite(Reset,LOW);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(Reset,HIGH);
  delay(3000);
  digitalWrite(PowerOn,LOW);
  delay(500);
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int8_t send_command(char* ATcommand, char* expected_answer, unsigned int timeout) {

  uint8_t x = 0,  answer = 0;
  char response[50];
  unsigned long previous;

  memset(response, '\0', 50);    // Initialice the string

  delay(100);

  while ( Serial.available() > 0) Serial.read();   // Clean the input buffer

    Serial.println();
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println(ATcommand);    // Send the AT command


  x = 0;
  previous = millis();

  // this loop waits for the answer
  do {
    if (Serial.available() != 0) {  // if there are data in the UART input buffer, reads it and checks for the asnwer
      response[x] = Serial.read();
      Serial.print(response[x]);
      x++;
      if (strstr(response, expected_answer) != NULL)    // check if the desired answer (OK) is in the response of the module
      {
        answer = 1;
      }
    }
  }

  while ((answer == 0) && ((millis() - previous)  0) Serial.read();   // Clean the input buffer
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void read_UART_buffer(char *buffer,int count, unsigned int timeOut) {
  int i = 0;
  unsigned long timerStart;
  timerStart = millis();

 while(1) {
  while  (Serial.available()!=0){  
    Serial.write(Serial.read());
    char c = Serial.read();
    buffer[i++] = c;

  }
  //buffer[i]='\0';
    if((unsigned long) (millis() - timerStart)  > timeOut * 1000UL) {
            break;
        }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the Content length is 41? Doesn't seem like it, make sure it's the same length as your message body.

This depends from server to server, but I think you should also put a CRLF after your message body.

Comment: The problem was in delays, seems its very important, got working code

Comment: can you give us your sketch source code